# X12 for seasonality adjustment - SAS

Tags: regression, arima, sas, seasonality

I found this code online and I wanted to dissect it before programming something similar in SAS.

The problem is idenitfy seasonality in a time series. I want to understand the code line by line:

```
proc x12 data=sales date=date season=12;
      var unempl_rate *already log differenced;
      transform function=none;
      regression predefined=td;
      automdl maxorder=(1,1)
              print=unitroottest unitroottestmdl autochoicemdl best5model;
      estimate;
      x11;
      output out=out(obs=23) a1 d11 d18;
   run;
   proc print data=out(obs=23);
      title 'Output Variables Related to Trading Day Regression';
   run;
```

By line:

> 1. the first line just defined use the x12 procedure with data set called "sales" - *monthly* data, indexed by variable "date" and expect a seasonality in
>    the data every 12 months.
> 2. this line tells which variable to analyze.
> 3. no transformation was necessary since a transformation was already done.
> 4. this line confuses me a little, is "regression predifined=td" applied for adjustment/outliers/events?
>
> 5-7. do these lines mean to estimate the
> best ARIMA (linear) models on the residual?
> 8-onwards. For outputing results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a thorough description of the methodology at Census web site, [here](https://www.census.gov/srd/www/x13as/). The current routine is X-13ARIMA-SEATS, it's very popular beyond Census Bureau.

In old days they used X-13. If you have annual seasonality in monthly series, then this is the way to go. They supply the routine for download. They have a ton of references on the subj.

MATLAB has a few examples with code and detailed explanations, e.g. see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/seasonal-adjustment-1.html?refresh=true)